# Make pgfplots' legend look like an array

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

Is there anyway to make the legend of pgfplots look like an array? For example, assume that I want to make a legend look like this, where the legend is `2*2` array:

**PS:** I am sorry that my figure is drawn by hand. In order to have the code you must have the data points as well (otherwise you cannot sketch it), thus, I thought that just this figure is sufficient.

[image]

Comment: It is already an array, or a matrix. You can use `legend style={ legend columns=2}`, etc.

Comment: @Lazysquirrel Thank you so much. It worked.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been resolved in question comments.

Comment: I think this is a potentially useful question and answer. Perhaps OP could include the code to make the figure and @Lazysquirrel could make their comment an answer?